# get number files and folders under a given folder

Tags: files, filesystems, file-copy

in Microsoft Windows you can right click on a folder for *Properties* and it will report **Contains *#* files and *#* folders**

Is there a way to do this in linux on the command line?

I want to know the total number of files and the total number of folders under a given folder as well as within any and all subfolders from that starting folder.

Answer (score 0):

The total number of directories under the directory called `dir` (including `dir` itself):

```
find dir -type d -exec echo x \; | wc -l
```

This locates any directory in or under `dir` (and `dir` itself) and outputs an `x` for each.  The the number of lines outputted is then counted with `wc -l`.

Doing it this way allows us to count also names containing newlines correctly.

The total number of non-directories (files) under `dir`:

```
find dir ! -type d -exec echo x \; | wc -l
```

On a system using GNU `find` (such as Linux), this may be sped up by replacing `-exec echo x \;` with `-printf 'x\n'`.

With the `tree` command, if available:

```
tree -a dir | tail -n 1
```

Comment: having trouble with `find dir ! -type d -exec echo x \; | wc -l` I am getting *invalid null command*

Comment: See also `-exec printf '%.0s\n' {} +` as seen in the dup to speed it up on non-GNU systems